# php file_get_contents authorization header

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Can anyone give me any explanation for why this authorization function for a private bitbucket repository is working on my local machine (running PHP Version 5.3.17) but is not authorizing on my remote server (running PHP Version 5.3.20)

I'm not getting an error per se -- i'm just getting a "forbidden" response from bitbucket. But everything works great running from my local server.

```
function bitBucketConnect($url){
    global $bitPassword;
    global $bitUsername;
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
     'http' => array(
       'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$bitUsername:$bitPassword")
       )
    ));

 // Make the request
 return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
 }
```

Comment: do you have permission to login from the ipaddress of your server? Looks like that ip is bocked, maybe bitbucket has a witelist of ips that can login?

Comment: The code itself should run fine with PHP5.2

Comment: You should *never* have a phpinfo.php file on your server. I strongly advice you to remove it as soon as possible. If you need to provide information on your server configuration, do *not* include information that enables people to 'identify' your server (e.g. hostname, ip-address)

Comment: gotcha - thanks - as you can tell I am a hobbiest :)

Comment: @John I wonder why they would block that ip though and not the ip of my local machine -- and more than that I wonder how I can figure out if your theory is true. Bitbucket does have a clear information about  whitelisting certain ips

Comment: I think the best option is to contact bitbucket/look though there faq/your settings.

Comment: checked with bitbucket and the confirmed my ip has not been blocked -- i've also had my hosting service update me to php5.3 server -- still not success. Would someone be willing to try out my function on their own PRIVATE bitBucket repository and confirm that it works for you as well?

Comment: Have you checked file encoding on both servers ?

Comment: Check the seventh note [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and try if it helps in your case.

Comment: User agente seems to be required on older versions.

Comment: @mimipc -- can you tell me how I would do that -- and what I would be looking for?

Comment: I know they are fast ways to do that with linux commands, but I prefer opening files with a text editor and saving them using the right encoding.

Comment: @budwiser -- is the seventh note the one suggesting a change for PHP 5.2.x? If so, they doesn't seem to be my problem since I had my hosting service update me to a 5.3.x server and the problem persists.

Comment: @Jeff Ok then, just a thought. Please update the current version in your question.

Comment: Have you tried a simple cURL call?, at least, that could give an idea whether it's a connectivity problem or a file_get_contents problem

Comment: I did re-write the code using a cURL call and this works -- so the problem definitely seems to be with the file_get_contents problem -- which as suggested below seems like a proxy problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your proxy will respond that authentication is required. You may scratch your head and think "but I'm providing authentication!"

The issue is that the 'header' value is only applicable to http connections. So to authenticate on a proxy, you first have to pull a file from HTTP, before the context is valid for using on FTP.

```
<?php 
$opts = array('ftp' => array( 
    'proxy' => 'tcp://vbinprst10:8080', 
    'request_fulluri'=>true, 
    'header' => array( 
        "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth" 
        ) 
    ), 
    'http' => array( 
    'proxy' => 'tcp://vbinprst10:8080', 
    'request_fulluri'=>true, 
    'header' => array( 
        "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth" 
        ) 
    ) 
); 
$context = stream_context_create($opts); 
$s = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com",false,$context); 
$s = file_get_contents("ftp://anonymous:anonymous@ftp.example.org",false,$context); 
?>
```

Comment: i have same problem when i send header with ("Authorization: Basic $auth")
i change it to ("Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth") and solved my problem
"Teun Lassche" thanks